# How To Display Data in DataTables From Two Query result?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, datatables

I tried to make attendance data report for students.
There are two column tables, the number of present and absent. To display the attendance column I use a query to calculate the number of attendees when the data contains 'Present'. Meanwhile, to count the number of absent I used another query with the condition that the data contains 'Alpa'.

In short, in my mind i have two query results

`$query1 = ... ;`

`$query2 = ... ;`

Can I display both in DataTables? if possible,
How do I display both of them in the datatables? Or is there another way to make just one query result?

This is my code

```
$query1 = DB::table('presensi AS ps')
              ->join('jadwal AS j', 'ps.id_jadwal', '=', 'j.id')
              ->join('mahasiswa AS m', 'ps.id_mahasiswa_taklim', '=', 'm.nim')
              ->join('mahasiswa_taklim AS mt', 'ps.id_mahasiswa_taklim', '=', 'mt.nim')
              ->join('kelompok AS k', 'mt.kd_kelompok', '=', 'k.kd_kelompok')
              ->selectRaw('count(ps.status_kehadiran) as jumlah_kehadiran, ps.id_mahasiswa_taklim, m.nama_mahasiswa')
              ->selectRaw('max(j.pertemuan) as jumlah_pertemuan')
              ->where('k.id_muallim', $user->no_identitas)
              ->where('ps.status_kehadiran', 'Hadir')
              ->groupBy('ps.id_mahasiswa_taklim')
              ->groupBy('m.nama_mahasiswa')
              ->get();
return DataTables::of(query1)->make(true);
```

A little bit of google translate to help the English speaking folks figure out what is going on in the query.

```
$query1 = DB::table('presence AS ps')
              ->join('schedule', 'ps.id_schedule', '=', 'schedule.id')
              ->join('college_student AS cs', 'ps.id_college_student_taklim', '=', 'cs.nim')
              ->join('college_student_taklim AS cst', 'ps.id_college_student_taklim', '=', 'cst.nim')
              ->join('group', 'cst.kd_group', '=', 'group.kd_group')
              ->selectRaw('count(ps.status_presence) as total_presence, ps.id_college_student_taklim, cs.name_college_student')
              ->selectRaw('max(schedule.meeting) as total_meeting')
              ->where('group.id_navigator', $user->no_identity)
              ->where('ps.status_presence', 'Present')
              ->groupBy('ps.id_college_student_taklim')
              ->groupBy('cs.name_college_student')
              ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can combine the results of two queries, you just need to combine the results into one array/collection.

However it is important that each query returns the data according to the column names and data formats of your datatable.

You can do:

```
    // Where $query1 and $query2 are the results collections
    $combined = [...$query1, ...$query2];
    return DataTables::of($combined)->make(true);
```

If you have the two queries, and each of them return the same names for the required columns, and the same data format for the required columns, then you can combine them in the manner above.